# Hydraulic motor sizing

Tags: pressure, hydraulics

[16 Examples of Tensile Strength](https://simplicable.com/new/tensile-strength) has a list of items and their tensile strength.

bamboo has these tensile strength ratings
Bamboo  MPA 350 PSI 50,763

If I needed to have a hydraulic motor to shred bamboo, the hydraulic motor ratings are in Nm, example
cc/rev 492
Nm/bar 6.86

cc/rev 197
Nm/bar 2.51

With the second hydraulic motor rated at 197 cc/rev and 2.51 Nm/bar

at 20bar system pressure the motor should output 50.2Nm of torque.

How do I calculate the required Nm needed to crush bamboo.
Newton Meters and MPA are different.

Comment: Some remarks: 1) I think that the given data in the hydraulic data sheet gives some information about the required input-force of the pump. When your hydraulic system pressure is 20 bar you need 50,2 Nm input of torque to your hydraulic pump. This amount of torque is in general delivered by an electromotor. 2) I think with a hydraulic pump you cannot shred bamboo. All the pump is delivering is oil flow at a certain pressure. 3) So in my opinion you need a machine that shreds the bamboo through rotation or translation. This machine can be powered by a hydraulic pump.